# dll for VBA looks empty

Tags: .net, vba, visual-studio, dll

I created a class library in vb.net, but the classes in the object browser seem to be empty (no attributes, functions).
[image]

I made the Assembly Com-Visible and registered it for COM-Interop.
[image]

I signed assembly.

In VBA referenced the tlb-File

Comment: `<[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>`.  Best to declare the interface explicitly, future-proofs it for .NET5+

Comment: I'm completly lost...
What is this?
Where do I declare the interface?
And when I google it, the results are "bad idea", "Do not use",...